# Splitting large file load into chunks, stitching to AudioBuffer?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In my app, I have an hour-long audio file that's entirely sound effects. Unfortunately I do need them all - they're species-specific sounds, so I can't cut any of them out. They were separate before, but I audiosprite'd them all into one large file.

The export file is about 20MB compressed, but it's still a large download for users with a slow connection. I need this file to be in an `AudioBuffer`, since I'm seeking to sections of an audioSprite and using `loopStart`/`loopEnd` to only loop that section. I more or less need the whole thing downloaded before playback can start, because the requested species are randomly picked when the app starts. They could be looking for sounds at the start of the file, or at the very end.

What I'm wondering is, if I were to split this file in fourths, could I load them in in parallel, and stitch them into the full `AudioBuffer` once loading finishes? I'm guessing I'd be merging multiple arrays, but only performing `decodeAudioData()` once? Requesting ~100 separate files (too many) was what brought me to audiosprites in the first place, but I'm wondering if there's a way to leverage some amount of async loading to lower the time it takes. I thought about having four `<audio>` elements and using `createMediaElementSource()` to load them, but my understanding is that I can't (?) turn a `MediaElementSource` into an `AudioBuffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider playing the files immediately in chucks instead of waiting for the entire file to download.  You could do this with the Streams API and:

1. Queuing chunks with the MediaSource Extensions (MSE) API and switching between buffers.
2. Playing back decoded PCM audio with the Web Audio API and `AudioBuffer`.

[See examples](https://fetch-stream-audio.anthum.com/) for low-latency audio playback of file chunks as they are received.

Comment: This might not exactly fit my particular problem (though I won't know until I try), since I need to access the full audio non-linearly, but this is probably the best answer for most people who encounter this SO question. I wasn't aware of these APIs - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in principle you can.  Just download each chunk as an ArrayBuffer, concatenate all of the chunks together and send that to `decodeAudioData`.

But if you're on a slow link, I'm not sure how downloading in parallel will help.

Comment: I opted to start plugging away at exactly that while waiting to see if anyone had a solution. You don't think downloading the file in asynchronous, parallel chunks would help at all?

Comment: I suppose it might help a little, but I would tend to think it would be much.  The connection is slow.  Having more downloads over the same slow connection doesn't seem that it would help.  If the server is the bottleneck, then maybe more will help (at the expense of everyone else using the server). But I'm not a networking expert.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** this code is functional, but on occasion produces really nasty audio glitches, so I don't recommend using it without further testing. I'm leaving it here in case it helps someone else figure out working with `Uint8Array`s.

So here's a basic version of it, basically what Raymond described. I haven't tested this with a split version of the large file yet, so I don't know if it improves the load speed at all, but it works. The JS is below, but if you want to test it yourself, [here's the pen.](https://codepen.io/tinstar/pen/EqLwwz)

```js
// mp3 link is from: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/JRaLVR

(function () {
  'use strict';

  const context = new AudioContext();
  let bufferList = [];

  // change the urlList for your needs
  const URL = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/Yodel_Sound_Effect.mp3';
  const urlList = [URL, URL, URL, URL, URL, URL];

  const loadButton = document.querySelector('.loadFile');
  const playButton = document.querySelector('.playFile');

  loadButton.onclick = () => loadAllFiles(urlList, loadProgress);

  function play(audioBuffer) {
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start();
  }

  // concatenates all the buffers into one collected ArrayBuffer
  function concatBufferList(buflist, len) {
    let tmp = new Uint8Array(len);
    let pos = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < buflist.length; i++) {
      tmp.set(new Uint8Array(buflist[i]), pos);
      pos += buflist[i].byteLength;
    }
    return tmp.buffer;
  }

  function loadAllFiles(list, onProgress) {
    let fileCount = 0;
    let fileSize = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      loadFileXML(list[i], loadProgress, i).then(e => {
        bufferList[i] = e.buf;
        fileSize += e.size;
        fileCount++;

        if (fileCount == bufferList.length) {
          let b = concatBufferList(bufferList, fileSize);
          context.decodeAudioData(b).then(audioBuffer => {
            playButton.disabled = false;
            playButton.onclick = () => play(audioBuffer);  
          }).catch(error => console.log(error));  
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // adapted from petervdn's audiobuffer-load on npm
  function loadFileXML(url, onProgress, index) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

      if (onProgress) {
        request.onprogress = event => {
          onProgress(event.loaded / event.total);
        };
      }

      request.onload = () => {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          const fileSize = request.response.byteLength;
          resolve({
            buf: request.response,
            size: fileSize
          });
        }
        else {
          reject(`Error loading '${url}' (${request.status})`);
        }
      };

      request.onerror = error => {
        reject(error);
      };

      request.send();
    });  
  }

  function loadProgress(e) {
    console.log("Progress: "+e);
  }
}());
```

Comment: `decodeAudioData()` requires the whole file to be download before playback begins.

Comment: Yes? Unless I'm wrong, this code downloads every file separately, assembles them into one combined buffer (`Uint8Array`), and performs `decodeAudioData()` once on that buffer. This doesn't solve slowness on the decoding end, but I generally noticed about ~3s of time saved. That said, I wasn't testing multiple connections, and I got some pretty nasty audio glitches a couple times that made me decide to abandon this method.